# IGMP Query Interval

Tags: multicast, igmp

What adverse effects could occurred if I set the igmp snooping querier query-interval to 1 second in the switch?

The default in switch is 60 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decreasing the query interval could needlessly increase the traffic on your LAN segment.

IGMP is between a host and a router, not a switch. A switch can snoop on IGMP, but it doesn't do IGMP queries.

Comment: Is it mean the IGMP snooping is different from IGMP querying?

Comment: IGMP queries are between a router and the hosts. The switch would normally be ignorant of IGMP, but IGMP snooping allows the switch to snoop on the queries so that it can send multicasts to only those switch ports which have hosts actually listening for those multicasts. Normally, a switch would flood multicasts to all ports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ron.
I still have not understand it clearly,
So without a router, is a host could get the multicast traffic send from the multicast source? 

I'm currently facing issue for the implementation of IPTV. When a host (in my case is android setopbox with igmp support) just recently boot up, the host couldn't play the IPTV channel. It must wait for around 2 minutes to play the channel. After that, if I stop and start again the channel, it's instantly play. I'm trying to shorten the query interval, but afraid of disturb the currently running switch in my network.

Comment: There is something else going on. The host will send an IGMP request when the application starts. A router would receive the request and forward multicasts out the router port, and it will query out that port every query interval to see if there are still hosts interested in receiving the multicast. If both the server and client are on the same layer-2 switch, in the same VLAN, I don't think IGMP plays a role in your problem. More likely the server is buffering for two minutes before it starts sending.

Comment: I think it's in the same VLAN, so it's pointless to set the IGMP Snooping querier query interval in the switch?
I haven't further investigate the work of server in sending multicast traffic to network, but I think the server is always broadcast the channel to network. When I check ethstats of the server, its showing `total:     0.00 Mb/s In    69.58 Mb/s Out -      0.9 p/s In    6405.4 p/s Out`
I need assistance to fix that behaviour, do I need to open another question? :D

Comment: That would be a question to ask on [su]. Questions about things like your server are off topic here.

Comment: From your point of view, is there a posibility it is a network problem?

Btw if the host and server in the same VLAN,  it's pointless to set the IGMP Snooping related in the switch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31986/discussion-between-hendrik-and-ron-maupin).

Answer (score 1):

The default, per spec is 125 seconds.

Set to 1 (one) second would result in a broadcast storm as every multicast capable device answers the query.

Comment: I believe the query interval is 125 seconds on NX-OS, but it is 60 seconds on IOS.

Comment: Checking the IOS router at hand, 120s. The 2960S's default to 125.

Comment: OK, obviously the real router wins. I looked at this [IP Multicast Commands](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ipmulti/command/reference/fiprmc_r/1rfmult1.html#wp1018626) for IOS 12.2, and this [Configuring IGMP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSmYz7xafJAhVGNz4KHaciD2AQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fc%2Fen%2Fus%2Ftd%2Fdocs%2Fswitches%2Fdatacenter%2Fsw%2Fnx-os%2Fmulticast%2Fconfiguration%2Fguide%2Fb_multicast%2Fb_multicast_chapter_011.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE5nH_KIkpA-YAS87FgyQGCY9pYKg&sig2=I_lCw1xTBxr0WirhYy1-wA&cad=rja) for NX-OS.